# MSI DLL Custom Actions is not working well in installshiled

Tags: dll, installshield, merge-module

I have created merge module project in InstallShield 2014.

I have added Custom Action in using CustomActions.dll.

This CustomAction dll has Install Function.

Example: customactions.dll

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved )
{
return TRUE;
}

UINT __stdcall Install ( MSIHANDLE hModule )
{
MessageBox(NULL, "Hello world", "CustomAction", MB_OK);
return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

UINT __stdcall SampleFunction2 ( MSIHANDLE hModule )
{
MessageBox(NULL, "Hello world", "CustomAction", MB_OK);
return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

After that,

I have built merge module project.

I have added merge module in Basic MSI Project.

I have built basic project.

I have installed using newly built installer.

I am unable to found message-box of custom action. it means custom action is not executed.

[image: installshield]

IMAGE: https://i.imgsafe.org/0ca963f930.png

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to know what is your problem? Or may be you need info on InstallShield CA properties? Please ask the question. So far what I see is the issue with your functions, but is this what you want to know?

Comment: I have added custom action in merge module project in installshiled. Setup does not hit custom action dll function. more info please see the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to first create the custom action in merge module project.
2. Built merge module and add this merge module file in Basic MSI Project.
3. Extract "Behaviour and Logic" in "Installation Designer" Tab.
4. Insert Custom Action in Sequences in "Custom Actions and Sequences".

PFA: Screenshot for more info.
[image: Insert Custom Action]

5. Add Custom Action in "Merge Module Custom Action" Option in "Insert Action".

PFA: Screenshot for more info
[image]

6. Select custom action you want to add in Basic Project and Click "OK"
7. You need to set which sequences after/before custom action execute.

After that,
I built Basic MSI Project.
Custom Action function(Install Function) hit when I execute setup.exe.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two things that may be tripping you up:

1. The actions in your merge module are not being sequenced or otherwise invoked by the consuming msi.

   If you just added the custom action definition to the merge module, and did nothing special in the consuming msi, it doesn't know when to run these actions. You will need to schedule it by editing the msi and inserting the action from your merge module.

   For debugging, I would probably suggest putting the custom action (and its scheduling) directly in the msi, just to temporarily reduce the complexity.
2. The entry points of your custom action DLL may not be what you think. By default, C++ "decorates" its function names. If you don't have a module definition file specifying their raw name, or an `extern "C"` applied to the function, they will be decorated. Try running `dumpbin /exports customactions.dll` to verify their names. If they don't match what you entered into your installer project, you will have to change one or the other until they do.

   (Use a Visual Studio command prompt to get dumpbin on your path if you have trouble finding it. Or use any other tool that can examine DLL exports.)

If either of these problems apply, you will not see your message box. However if it's only the latter, you should see an error from Windows Installer when it cannot find the entry point. A verbose log can help clarify at that point; if the former applies, you'd have to search it for the lack of your custom action call.

Answer (score -1):

> I am unable to found message-box of custom action. it means custom action is not executed.

C++ MessageBox will not be executed by msiexec. Doesn't matter where you put your CustomAction.dll, you will not see your message box. This is not the way to identify if your CA get triggered. Your options are:

**The best way** is to monitor verbose installation log. You would see in the log if your CA was triggered.

**Use logging** inside your CA. The following function would log CA messages into MSI log:

```
void HelperMsiWriteLog( MSIHANDLE hInstall, LPCWSTR pszMsg )
{
  PMSIHANDLE hRecord = MsiCreateRecord(1);
  MsiRecordSetStringW( hRecord, 0, L"CA Log: [1]" );
  MsiRecordSetStringW( hRecord, 1, pszMsg );
  MsiProcessMessage( hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE_INFO, hRecord );
}
```

And you may call it in your CA function as following:

```
HelperMsiWriteLog( hInstall, L"my CA log message" );
```

Of cause you may **use message box**, but this would be Message Box from MSI, not C++ one. The following function will produce messagebox:

```
UINT HelperMsiMessageBox( MSIHANDLE hInstall, LPCWSTR pszMsg, DWORD dwOptions )
{
  PMSIHANDLE hRecord = MsiCreateRecord(1);
  MsiRecordSetStringW( hRecord, 0, L"[1]" );
  MsiRecordSetStringW( hRecord, 1, pszMsg );
  return MsiProcessMessage( hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE( INSTALLMESSAGE_USER | dwOptions ), hRecord );
}
```

And you may call it in your CA function as following:

```
HelperMsiMessageBox( hInstall, L"my CA messagebox message", MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK );
```

Comment: The message box in the C++ custom action WILL be triggered, don't make wrong answers please. Its the best way to debug it, add MessageBox and attach to the process...